# split the div into several equal parts

Tags: css

I need to make a div and it has 3 columns in the first, let's say 5 lines, in the second column also 5 lines and in the third 3 lines, but I need to make these 3 lines stretch to the full height

**It should be like this**

[image]

**I tried**

```css
.base {
  /*make it 100% width and a minimum of 1000px width*/
  width: auto;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  min-width: 1000px;
  padding: 0px;
  display: table;
}

.base-row {
  Display: table-row;
}

.base li {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 33%;
}

.cell1 {
  background-color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<div class=”base”>
  <ul class=”base-row”>
    <li class="cell1">
      <div class="content1">.....Lots of Content....</div>
    </li>
    <li class="cell1">
      <div class="content2">.....Lots of content....</div>
    </li>
    <li class="cell1">
      <div class="content3">.....Lots of content....</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use flex to style your layout. Set `display: flex` to the container, then set each column with

```
flex-grow: 1;
flex-basis: 0;
flex-shrink: 0;
```

This will make sure the columns will have equal width.
Then set

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
```

To each column, it will arrange the elements inside vertically. Also set

```
flex-grow: 1;
flex-basis: 0;
flex-shrink: 0;
```

to the rows and add as many rows as you want in each column.

```css
.cont{
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.col{
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.row{
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="row">1</div>
    <div class="row">2</div>
    <div class="row">3</div>
    <div class="row">4</div>
    <div class="row">5</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="row">a</div>
    <div class="row">b</div>
    <div class="row">c</div>
    <div class="row">d</div>
    <div class="row">e</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="row">111</div>
    <div class="row">222</div>
    <div class="row">333</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  max-width: 991px;
  display: flex;
}

.col {
  width: 33.3%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.col div {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 20px 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="col">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Use `flex-grow: 1` on the div that you wanted to be stretched. Hope it'll help